# Lifesteal from wards

Tags: league-of-legends

So as far as I know you can lifesteal from wards.

1. But how does it work?
2. Does it recover the same amount of life even if you have more lifesteal?
3. Does the damage affect the health you steal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not tested it recently but I've seen a Riot Developer post from 2013 where he says:

> This is true for all champions -- they lifesteal off wards. It's one of those "unintended but not truly a bug" details that we've kept in based on a judgment that it leads to slightly more interesting gameplay than cutting it would. Personally, it feels odd to lifesteal so much from a tiny 3 hp stick.

Source: http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=4129105

Based on the other discussions it seems as though you heal the full amount you normally would for each hit on the ward. I know you can get Nasus Q stacks for using it on the last hit on a ward as I've tried that myself.

Comment: Don't forget that it's also possible to crit on wards.

Comment: @Jutschge Will that increase the life stolen from the ward?

Comment: @Izzo yes. It shows as a Critical 1 damage but it will apply a Crit depending on your AD/Critchance and thus the lifesteal

Answer (score 1):

> 1. But how does it work?

Wards, Teemo Shrooms, Shaco Boxes, etc. are all treated as "pets."  Since they "belong" to a specific champion, damage dealt is calculated, you lifesteal from that damage (then the ward reduces the damage to one).

> 2. Does it recover the same amount of life even if you have more lifesteal?

This depends on the amount of damage you deal.  If you have 20% lifesteal and deal 400 damage (think Caitlyn Auto late game), you will get back 80 health.  If you crit, and deal 800 damage, you'll get back 160 health.

> 3. Does the damage affect the health you steal?

Yes, see above.

Source:  Platinum ELO ADC main